# How to implement daily sunset/sunrise times to android studio application

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I am developing an android application. I have decided to develop an application that tells the user the daily times to pray for Muslims. But as I am new to android(and also programming in general) I don't know how to implement this. I have done some research myself and found that some web services provide JSON or XML files to fetch the data or there supposed to be Java Tools/Libs to use. I need help on putting this data into my program and i dont know if i have to change it everyday or will the time change everyday, if there are any experts out there who can break it down for me it would help me a lot.

thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API for sunrise and sunset timings of a particular lat long pair
https://sunrise-sunset.org/api

You can use Date library in Android and fetch current date.

To get the latest information all the time, you can hit the Api upon activity Start.

Comment: Thank you. How exactly do i get the daily info from there? like, what  is the syntax? Using retrofit

Comment: Please follow this article

https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23