# How to get sunrise / sunset from android without location permissions

Tags: android

I want to get the sunrise / sunset local times (without calculate it myself by location, timezone etc.), just to get it from the android system, wherever the device is currently located.

Is that possible, and how?

I have been tried to find the solution in the internet, and even asked ChatGPT (AI), but I didn't found any answer.

Comment: The OS does not provide that information directly. You can derive that information using latitude, longitude, time of day, and (I assume) a database of sunrise/sunset information. To get the latitude and longitude, either you need location permission (and use GPS) or you use some public geolocation API (and find out the latitude and longitude associated with the user's public IP address, which may be hundreds of kilometers away).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of an API for that. Android by itself can't provide you with this type of information.
This seems like a duplicate question :
[How to implement daily sunset/sunrise times to android studio application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71836304/how-to-implement-daily-sunset-sunrise-times-to-android-studio-application)